# Will range based for loop in c++ preserve the index order

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

In c++11, if I use a range based for loop on vector, will it guarantee the iteration order?

i.e. are the following code blocks guaranteed to produce the same output?

```
vector<T> output;
vector<U> V;
for( auto v: V) output.push_back(f(v));
```

vs

```
for(int i =0; i < V.size(); ++i) output.push_back(f(V[i]));
```

what if it is not `vector` but `map`, etc?

Comment: You could certainly optimize a bit an unnecessary copy by doing `auto&` instead of `auto`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes the two codes are guaranteed to do the same. Though I don't have a link to the standard you can have a look [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for). I quote: `You can read that as "for all x in v" going through starting with v.begin() and iterating to v.end().`

Comment: or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj203382.aspx)
Executes statement repeatedly and **sequentially** for each element in expression.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, they are equivalent.  The standard guarantees in 6.5.4:

> For a range-based for statement of the form
>
> `for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement`
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the expression surrounded by parentheses ( expression )
>
> and for a range-based for statement of the form
>
> `for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list ) statement`
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the braced-init-list. In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
      __end = end-expr;
      __begin != __end;
      ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

> where `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` are variables defined for exposition only, and `_RangeT` is the type of the expression, and `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are determined as follows:
>
> — if `_RangeT` is an array type, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, where `__bound` is the array bound. If `_RangeT` is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — if `_RangeT` is a class type, the unqualified-ids `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT`
>   as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`, respectively;
>
> — otherwise, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace `std` is an associated namespace.

Though your question about map is a bit nonsensical.  If it's an ordered map and you iterate through the map properly, then they're equivalent.  If it's an unordered map then your question doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 10):

Yes and no (It depends on the container in use):

- The range based for is a loop like for(iterator pos = range.begin(); pos !=
  range.end(); ++pos) { /* with a range variable = *pos */ ... }
- An operator [] might do something different (eg. a std::map operator does a lookup on the key and create a new entry, if the key does not exist)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int, int> map;
    map m = { { 0, 0 }, { 2, 2 }, { 4, 4 } };
    for(const auto& e : m) {
        std::cout << e.first << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(map::size_type i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << m[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
0 2 4 
0 0 2 0 4
```

(The second result might be a good shot in the own foot or even intended)

Comment: You should probably point out that either way the user is doing something dreadfully wrong in this example.  If you have sequential indexes on a `map` with keytype `int`, then you shouldn't be using a `map`, you should be using a `deque` or `vector` or `array`.  If you do not have sequential indexes, then you should be iterating using iterators, not using `for (int i = 0; i < blah; ++i)`